# Selecting checkboxes on dropdown select

Tags: jquery

working on some Jquery code it goes like this

```
 $(function(){
     $("select").change(function() {                
         $(".class1").each(function(index) {                                
             if($("select option:selected").text()== $(this).text()) {
                  $(".class2:eq(index)").prop('checked', true);                 
             }  
         })
     })
 })

<INPUT TYPE="CheckBox" CLASS='class2'> 
<TD CLASS=class1>content1</TD>
```

i wanted to comapre the dropdown selected value to a certain class' elements and wants to check checkboxes of that same index in another class
but its not working at all please help

Comment: if you could paste the html?

Comment: <INPUT TYPE="CheckBox" CLASS='class2'>    <TD CLASS=class1>content1</TD>

Comment: not here you can paste all the corresponding html at your post.

Comment: Yeah ! Thanks Yograj ...Finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$(".class2:eq(index)").prop('checked', true);
```

to

```
$(".class2:eq("+index+")").prop('checked', true);
```

or

```
$(".class2").eq(index).prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

even you can try this:

```
 $(".class2").index(index).prop('checked', true);
```

more edits:

```
$("select").change(function() {
     var selText = $("option:selected", this).text(); // <--get the text here
     $(".class1").each(function(index) {                                
         if(selText== $(this).text()) {  //<---then compare here
              $(".class2").eq(index).prop('checked', true);                 
         }  
     });
 });
```

Comment: my comaprison part is working fine its just the contents inside if block that are not working